# Javascript accessing object variable from another callback without placing variable in global scope

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, global-variables

I have the following scenario. I have an object 'a' with two callback methods however one callback requires access to the other callback variable value (*for modifications / to read value / update value*). I would like to know what is the best approach to structuring this code without placing the variable b into global scope. Under is the code and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/thbebexb/).

**Code**

```
var a = {

    load: function(){

        var b = 25;
        console.log(b);

    },

    add : function (b){

        console.log('The value of b is '+ b);
    }


};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a closure:

```
var module = (function () {
    var b; //Scoped to this module

    return { //Return object with methods
        load: function () {
            b = 25; //This refers to the module's b
            console.log(b);
        },
        add: function () {
            console.log('The value of b is '+ b);
        }
    };
})(); //Self invoking function, invokes instantly.

module.load(); //b is now 25.
module.add(); //The value of b is 25
console.log(b); //undefined, out of scope.
```

Now all the "private" variables are scoped directly to the module, and don't affect global scope.

Comment: module.add() returns undefined not 25

Comment: My bad, no need to pass anything to `add`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Alternative 1: Using a "private" variable
function A(b) {
    // seal b in closure
    var b = b;

    this.load = function(){
        b = 25;
        console.log(b);
    };

    this.add  = function(){
        console.log('The value of b is '+ b);
    };

    this.getB = function(){
      return b;
    };
}

// Alternative 2: Using a object property
function A(b) {
    // seal b in closure
    this.b = b;

    this.load = function(){
        this.b = 25;
        console.log(this.b);
    };

    this.add = .add = function(){
        console.log('The value of b is '+ this.b);
    };
}

var a = new A('foo');
var callback = a.load; 

// ...
```